# Active::Job and Shoryuken do action on SIGTERM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, rails-activejob, shoryuken

In my rails app, I have a Shoryuken runner as a runner on a Kubernetes Stack.

I have some long running job, and I want to do some action when the worker pod is stopped.

As far as I know, Kubernetes send a SIGTERM to the worker. I wish to catch this SIGTERM in my job to, for instance, retry the running job.
But it seems that the signal cannot be catch in the job.

Any idea?

Comment: Please,read https://foxutech.medium.com/kubernetes-pod-graceful-shutdown-how-a9a46e0b1e53.